App Crashing while trying to use Firebase analytics
Im developing a C++ Desktop application and trying to use Firebase Analytics using the Firebase C++ SDK from https://firebase.google.com/download/cpp
I tried initializing the analytics module but the application crashes.
Have added firebase_analytics.lib and included necessary header files.
#include <iostream>
#include "firebase/app.h"
#include "firebase/analytics.h"
#include "firebase/analytics/event_names.h"
#include "firebase/analytics/parameter_names.h"
#include "firebase/analytics//user_property_names.h"

int main()
{
    firebase::AppOptions appOptions;
    appOptions.set_api_key("project_api_key"); // pass the necessary details
    appOptions.set_app_id("app_id");
    appOptions.set_project_id("project_id");

    firebase::App* firebaseApp = firebase::App::Create(appOptions);
    firebase::analytics::Initialize(*firebaseApp);
    firebase::analytics::SetAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(true);
    delete firebaseApp;
}

The crash occurs on this line
firebase::analytics::Initialize(*firebaseApp);

Are you sure that firebaseApp is a valid pointer?

Yes, it is a valid pointer
